# Selenium Chrome issue - Execution stops at GoToUrl() when an alert is shown

Tags: c#, selenium

I have an issue which I cannot find so much information about. I have an internal company page (the one shown is just illustration) which when opened in the browser shows a pop-up window where I need to enter the username and password. Now for InternetExplorer and Firefox this works just fine. The code navigates to the desiredUri, the page opens and the execution goes further to the "var alert = driver.SwitchTo()..." and then I enter the username and password and all is ok. But with Chrome the execution actually stops at `driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(desiredUri);`!!!

So the driver tries to open the page and while opening the authentication alert is shown but then it just hang there. Manually I can enter the username and password and then it works but via the code I cannot find the way how to do it because it never goes to the `var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();` line which works perfectly for IE and FF.
Any ideas why chrome behaves in this way and is there a way to come around the issue? I have tried to enter username and password directly as the URL `http://username:password@www.` but it does not work for my internal page and the pop-up alert is still shown.

```
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9515"), optionsChrome.ToCapabilities())
String desiredUri = "http://www.internalcompanypage.com";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(desiredUri);
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.SendKeys(_credentials.UserName);
```

Any input about this issue is appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WebDriverWait` :

```
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(optionsChrome.ToCapabilities())
String desiredUri = "http://www.internalcompanypage.com";
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(desiredUri);
var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
Wait.Until(c => c.FindElement(By.Id(_credentials.UserName)));
alert.SendKeys(_credentials.UserName);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunatelly it gives the same results. When the execution comes to the `..GoToUrl()` line it stops there. Again `var alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();` is never reached. If I don´t enter anything manually I get exception **The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:9515/session/15f6195a63bb08c5dec0956547636b40/url timed out after 60 seconds.**

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I was not working last days. The code is not running without "localhost:9515". It cannot start a browser and I get an exception due to that.